# Extend non-client area on form with custom drawn titlebar

Tags: vb.net, windows, winforms, aero

I used the awesome tutorial at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44235/Painting-Vista-s-Aero-NonClientArea-in-VB-NET to make my form have custom non-client area controls. It now looks like so:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRKQt.png
[image: custom non client area]

I would like to make it so that the non-client area extends all the way down to the TabControl page start, so the logo is completely in the non-client area and there is no grey at the top of the window.

Answer (score 0):

Find this line in the form's code:

```
dwmMargins.cyTopHeight = nccsp.rect2.Top - nccsp.rect1.Top
```

Now just add however many pixels you need:

```
 dwmMargins.cyTopHeight = nccsp.rect2.Top - nccsp.rect1.Top + x
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you can use DLL's, I found this:

Download this DLL: http://www.mediafire.com/download/jmvjiu2wty4/rtaGlassEffectsLib.dll

Then create an instance of `rtaGlassEffect`

```
Dim glass As New rtaGlassEffectsLib.rtaGlassEffect
```

Finally put this in your form's `Load` event handler:

```
glass.TopBarSize = yourSize
glass.ShowEffect(Me)
```

Comment: I don't suppose you have a more reliable source to link to than mediafire?